# Nginx redirect domain with trailing slash

Tags: nginx, redirect, seo

Is it possible to redirect url http://example.com/ to http://example.com without trailing slash ? My SEO specialist said to hide 'http://example.com/' from google index. And I am confused about it.

Comment: Read [this post on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/597302/removing-the-trailing-slash-from-a-url-with-nginx).

Comment: However, In the Google Search Console, Google itself adds trailing slashes to all registered domains.

Comment: They are the same. Some browsers hide a solitary `/` following the domain name in the address bar, but the URI received by the server will always contain at least one character, which begins with `/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx redirect without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579921/nginx-redirect-without-trailing-slash)